# Typescript function to check if property is null or undefined, but fully typed and guarded

Tags: typescript

I've seen similar questions about a function to check if something is null or undefined, but I'm looking for something more guarded.

The best answer I've seen is something like

```
export function isNullOrUndefined<T>(value: T | undefined | null): value is null | undefined {
 return value === null || value === undefined
}
```

Now this works, but I want the function to throw an error if a non nullable/undefinable type has been passed in and also return if the value is null | undefined. That way if it's used in an if statement, inside the if, it knows that the property is defined.

I tried this

```
export function isNullOrUndefined<T extends (undefined extends T ? any : null extends T ? any : undefined | null)>(
  value: T
): value is (T extends undefined ? T : T extends null ? T : never){
  return value === undefined || value === null;
}
```

Which mostly worked, but it had issues with things like unknowns and keyof properties.

Is there a way to do exactly what I'm looking for?

EDIT: Added link to show cases where it works and where it fails.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAkFEGVtAdQPICUDSoCCtTQBoAK0AwuNACIBQAZgK4B2AxgC4CWA9g6CwKYDOLAHJ0ANqOQAnAKoMAJrxpsGvOQAoGAQwC2vAFyhBk5QHMAlAYBGHDqN6aGAbyqhXoNjTVt+I8VNkKSirqWrpmZo6gIDwAFpIcAO78oLyS8ZIANKCibADWvO4shjEcYnIubpWSvCx0ktwsknS8ANwVrgC+7aDVtfWgNJqi-K1UXbSMrJwNAsJiEjLyisqqAEwaOrwA-AZGphag1rb2Tt0eXj7z-ktBqhthEVFgCRySuckm1Zos3VU1dQ0mqNKl1KkwuPxjgA6UQcEz3XhmFpPHgATwADgVvIZGqYsjl8oViqVROU-n1uINhqNxvRmOwuDxZr4FgFlsFoAAPdE5JhsFiIfkxWS5BiJBgInagRii8UHI52BzOSruGigBGgACEAF5tdKbis5KAAGTGtGYjhq0IFHV6gDkewYJjtZlAkWifEEplAmhMmmUgn1gUN7gYgnsRst0v43rpU0ZLze-F+sXiCVAKnT0DSrzUdt43N4rFUGc2PA4h30OOMTpdbRBVG64LD0Nh8OtSJRLAxWOSjpMoAAPkH2ap8XksUV+CUypXur0AQMhiM2uMqNEoHAEBRkEI7eAkGhMDg8ERSORqHGGTNBCzrsHgoKWDF0LxUcgaOAADzgAB8koMfJUSjcB5RsRVTkqc5vDvRYHzuDtHmiVJ0lTcVQBiVJeCySw6CnGdSQYO0fhVNwF36RpmnrNxQTI-5+ipFcxkbK9piZW8rjg0c5CfYUGFlBIJWtKUZTFQSwOOJVQDOTxNRgzi2VuEJNldU1zV4KNrS1XVQAdXFawiFNXHIwEqO6WjXGbSE7BhOEEU7D0e3cPt9JMLJpxJI1LAKfshxHJT53oyllxpRt1zAAAxaQhDIABJXcJnpNj5L8LilJ-FJOT4eRkjURh4KNAtsrkZIDy2H0GFRUADAYeZMuK0rQHKhwqoMfLuL82rxDMf8KgANyGZoDHAKgDgG0Rmmc9UDyK3gcv8kNyoPYb6rmkqMzqpbqozXg+tSQzjKC0Bxsm3U9XapSh2HE6CjOjbxFXIA

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve] that demonstrates what issues you are having problem with; perhaps some lines of code that show specifically "issues with things like unknowns and keyof properties".

Comment: Good idea, I added a link to typescript playground to show the issues with the function that almost works

Comment: So by "keyof properties" you meant "unspecified type parameter" (since `x?: keyof Someinterface` wouldn't give you the problem).  When faced with a conditional type that depends on an unspecified type parameter, the compiler defers evaluating it and it does not put in a lot of effort to verify that a value is assignable to it.  That makes your `keyof T` situation nearly impossible to solve, as far as I can tell.  You're going to have to put up with some false positives or false negatives, I'm afraid.  I can fix the issue with `unknown` I think, but unspecified generics is ‍♂️

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks for your help! I'll probably go with '== null' or '!= null' then, combined with eslint rules that should be good enough.